# MinGW compiler for Qt 5.5 MSVC 2013 version

Tags: qt

I've installed Qt 5.5 MSVC 2013 version on my Windows 7 64bit PC. The problem is that I don't have Visual Studio 2013 installed on my PC. I've Visual Studio 2012. But my Qt does not detect compilers from Visual Studio 2012. Is it possible to use MinGW as compiler in Qt  5.5 MSVC 2013?

Comment: How can a fundamental question about compiler toolchains be offtopic, at least because of this reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not possible. Especially on Windows, you have to use any C++ libraries built with the same toolchain you are using to build the application.

So if you want to use MinGW toolchain, you have to use MinGW version of Qt libs (be it with installer or by building it yourself). If you want to use some MSVC version, you need matching version of Qt, etc.

Note that you should be able to use the free "Express" version of MSVC (as long as it is the right "year" and service pack version), if you really want to go with MSVC. However, since Qt installer can install the MinGW toolchain, it's much easier, no special setup needed.

Comment: OK.  Thanks for the reply.